# How to run Android-x86 4.2 ISO on VM VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, android, iso-image

I installed Oracle VirtualBox on Win7, then I downloaded [android-x86-4.2-20121225.iso](http://android-x86.googlecode.com/files/android-x86-4.2-20121225.iso) from [Android-x86 - Porting Android to x86](http://www.android-x86.org/download). After I installed Android x86-4.2 on VirtualBox from ISO and creating fake SD Card for it, I tried to run it, but when I started it I saw these lines in console:

```
Detecting Android-x86... found at /dev/sda1

ANDROID root@x86:/ #
```

And no thing else. I tried that some times but result is the same. How I can solve this problem?

**Update:** Even I waited more than 20 minutes and nothing happen!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to change the value of "androidboot.hardware" parameter in the grub command from "Android-x86" to "x86".
You can do this by pressing "Tab" in the boot menu or by editing "isolinux.cfg" file on the installation ISO Image.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you,that works for me!Although it takes some times.

Answer (score 1):

I have an HP430 Laptop with Windows 7. I had the same problem. But I figured out the solution:

While booting the computer with Windows 7 I entered the BIOS menu. There was a option to optimize the PC for virtualization. I selected it. After that every thing ran smoothly.

Later I noticed that in VirtualBox, in  system settings, the acceleration type was VT-x AMD, Nested Paging, PAE/NX. This was different before optimization.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer appears 9 months ago on youtube:

- Close VM
- In the system tab under settings for the Android machine uncheck "hardware clock in UTC time"
- In the display tab set graphics controller to "vboxvga" and enable 3D hardware acceleration

The "Android" screen should appears under one minute after the message `ANDROID root@x86:/ #` where you get stuck

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait more. I think it will start, but you have just wait enough.

Comment: It's more likely that there are no graphics drivers in the recent ISO image. Official VirtualBox support is non-existant since ICS.

Comment: @RistoSalminen I wait more than 20 minuets and no thing happen!

Comment: Oh, that's sad. Then you have more serious/hard problem.